# "+","[","]" in Regular expression did not take effect in Linux C

Tags: c, regex

I got a program written in C language which could apply regular expression to a string.

However,it only works for the regular expression

```
\\w ('\\' means single '\' in string).

\\w+ \\s+ \\s or [^\\s]+  
did not take effect.
```

It seems that,

```
"^","[","]","+"
```

was not recognized by the program.

The program was running as the format below:

```
./program {regular expression}
```

Then input a line of string,the program would apply the regular expression to the string and give result.

I check the program and have not found anything wrong.

```
/* the function get a substring from a string */
static char* substr(const char*str,unsigned start, unsigned end)
{
  unsigned n = end - start;
  static char stbuf[256];
  strncpy(stbuf, str + start, n);
  stbuf[n] = 0;
  return stbuf;
}

/* the main program */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char * pattern;
  int x, z, lno = 0, cflags = 0;
  char ebuf[128], lbuf[256];
  regex_t reg;
  regmatch_t pm[10];
  const size_t nmatch = 10;
  /* complie regular expression*/
  pattern = argv[1];
  z = regcomp(&reg, pattern, cflags);
  if (z != 0){
  regerror(z, &reg, ebuf, sizeof(ebuf));
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: pattern '%s' \n",ebuf, pattern);
   return 1;
  }
/* get the line of input string */
  while(fgets(lbuf, sizeof(lbuf), stdin))
  {
    ++lno;
    if ((z=strlen(lbuf)) > 0 && lbuf[z-1] == '\n')
    lbuf[z - 1] = 0;
    /* match input line with regular expression */
    z = regexec(&reg, lbuf, nmatch, pm, 0);
    if (z == REG_NOMATCH){printf("not match\n,pattern is %s\n",pattern);     
continue;}
    else if (z != 0) {
      regerror(z, &reg, ebuf, sizeof(ebuf));
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: regcom('%s')\n", ebuf, lbuf);
      return 2;
    }  printf(" $%d='%s'\n", x, substr(lbuf, pm[x].rm_so, pm[x].rm_eo));};
    }
  }
  /*releasing the compiled regular expresion struct*/
  regfree(&reg);
 return 0;
}
    /* Deal with output result  */
    for (x = 0; x < nmatch && pm[x].rm_so != -1; ++ x)
    {
      if (!x) {printf("%04d: %s\n", lno, lbuf);
       printf(" pattern is %s",pattern);
       printf(" $%d='%s'\n", x, substr(lbuf, pm[x].rm_so, pm[x].rm_eo));};
    }
  }
  /*releasing the compiled regular expresion struct*/
  regfree(&reg);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using single quotes around your argument when you pass it to your program.

Comment: Also, try with `cflags = REG_EXTENDED`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. there's no need to be so sarcastic.  They clearly specified their problem: "It seems that "^","[","]","+" did not recognized by the program."  In context, it is clear that "I check the program and have not found anything wrong." means that they are unable to find the problem in their code

Comment: Start with a very simple program that [prints the value of `argc` and the strings in `argv`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1285/command-line-arguments/4435/printing-the-command-line-arguments#t=201611171904254708005).

Comment: It seems the `REG_EXTENDED` flag allows the use of `\w`, `\s`, and even `[^\s]` (gcc 5.1).

Comment: Just double checked and `REG_EXTENDED` does not let you use shorthand character classes inside bracket expressions (like `[^\s]`). See https://ideone.com/h0O8O5